# AlertController with Radio buttons

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I want put 2 radio buttons for male and female on an alertcontroller. I've got this:

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Add Participant',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      placeholder: 'Name'
    },
    {
      name: 'surname',
      placeholder: 'Surname'
    },
    {
      name: 'radiom',
      type: 'radio',
      label: 'Male',
      value: 'M'
    },
    {
      name: 'radiof',
      type: 'radio',
      label: 'Female',
      value: 'F'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Add',
      handler: data => {
        const newParticipant = this.participantsList.push([]);

        newParticipant.set({
          id: newParticipant.key,
          name: data.name,
          surname: data.surname,
          paid: false,
          sex: data.radiom
        });
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

But it doesn't look like something I've already see: I can't see the labels 'Male' and 'Female' and the radio buttons seem to be "old", I can select both of them, something completly different from the radioalert in the Ionic documentation. Moreover, how I can push to the list the value of 'M' or 'F' in the property 'sex'?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately you can't mix radio button with other input types like text in Ionic AlertController. The simplest solution is creating modal page with this form and pass data back from this modal to your page. I made simple example for you on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jum7ch

**In your page:**

```js
openAlert(){
 let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ParticipantModalPage);
     addModal.onDidDismiss((participant) => {
     if(participant){
     // handle participant date here
     this.participant = participant;
     console.log('data from modal: ', participant);
     }
 });
 addModal.present();
}
```

**In modal page:**

```js
returnParticipant() {
    let participant = {
    name: this.name,
    surname: this.surname,
    sex: this.sex
    };
    this.view.dismiss(participant);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow ionic3 official document for how to show radio button with alert box.

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  showRadio() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert.setTitle('Lightsaber color');

    alert.addInput({
      type: 'radio',
      label: 'Blue',
      value: 'blue',
      checked: true
    });

    alert.addButton('Cancel');
    alert.addButton({
      text: 'OK',
      handler: data => {
        this.testRadioOpen = false;
        this.testRadioResult = data;
      }
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

**This [document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) help you for change styles according to your wise and come end of page and follow material design styles.**